# ngRoute breaks everytime I add moment-picker as a dependency

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-3rd-party

My ngRoute breaks everytime I add another dependency. I want to add the 'moment-picker' to my app to pick dates and times but once I add the dependency to the module, I get the following error:

*Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]*

On the error page under 'Discription' it shows 'Using ngRoute'.

This is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('weather', ['ngRoute', 'moment-picker']);
```

If I remove the 'moment-picker' the ngRoute works perfectly without any errors.

I have tried switching my links to my scripts around, but no luck.

Comment: To reproduce the problem we need to see the libraries that you are loading and the order in which you are loading them.

Comment: I don't think it is ngRoute per se that breaks. Your dependency injection gets broken, so nothing would work. As @georgeawg said, it would be helpful to see the order you order your scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my problem was the order of scripts added, as well as that at a point I removed the 'moment-withh-locales.js' script.

My order now is:

```
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-moment-picker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/angular-moment-picker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In app.js my code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('weather', ['ngRoute', 'moment-picker']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) 
{
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl : "home.php"
    })
    .when("/page1", {
      templateUrl : "page1.php"
    });
});

app.config(['momentPickerProvider', function (momentPickerProvider) {momentPickerProvider.options(
{
    /* Picker properties */
    locale:        'en',
    format:        'L LTS',
    minView:       'decade',
    maxView:       'minute',
    startView:     'year',
    autoclose:     true,
    today:         false,
    keyboard:      false,

    /* Extra: Views properties */
    leftArrow:     '&larr;',
    rightArrow:    '&rarr;',
    yearsFormat:   'YYYY',
    monthsFormat:  'MMM',
    daysFormat:    'D',
    hoursFormat:   'HH:[00]',
    minutesFormat: moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LT').replace(/[aA]/, ''),
    secondsFormat: 'ss',
    minutesStep:   5,
    secondsStep:   1
    });
}]);
```

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Is this code acceptable having two 'app.config'? It seems really wrong how I'm doing it here, but it does work.

Comment: In general, jQuery should be loaded before angular.js so that it can be used by angular.element. Is there a specific reason you loaded it after angular.js?

Comment: Also bootstrap.js has a tendency to fight angular.js and cause problems. Is that library really necessary?

Comment: According to [angular-moment-picker readme](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker) *Angular Moment Picker is a native AngularJS directive for date and time picker that uses Moment.js and does not require jQuery.* What is the specific reason for loading jQuery?

Comment: @georgeawg Without jQuery and bootstrap.js there are some of my web-app's functionality that doesn't work such as the navigation dropdown.

Comment: Consider using [tag:angular-ui-bootstrap], a set of AngularJS directives based on Twitter Bootstrap's markup and CSS, **without any dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Angular Moment Picker](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/), make sure you have added the corresponding tags to your `index.html` file (depending on the version that you use):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/master/dist/angular-moment-picker.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/master/dist/angular-moment-picker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

`<link>` tags usually go inside your `<head>` tag at the beggining, while `<script>` tags usually take place inside your `<body>` tag, at the end of that.

Comment: Thank you, as just said in my answer, it must have been the order you gave me above that fixed it, as well as how I added my app.config. I do however get this error now with the moment-with-locales.js: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?|?/: Nothing to repeat_

Comment: The problem now is about the Regex 
Can you make a `console.log(moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LT'))` before you pass the options to `momentPickerProvider`? What's the output?

Also, it would be helpful if you provide a more detailed error output, like including the line and the file where the error is found.

Comment: The output is h:mm A

Comment: Ok. Can you show me the full error output that you get?

Comment: That is all I get. The result in the console line is **h:mm A**  The error I get refers to moment-with-locales.js:3346 and in that line is `meridiemParse: /?|?/,` and ` /?|?/,` is underlined red.

Comment: Hmmm that's weird. I just noticed you are loading both `moment.min.js` and `moment-with-locales.js`. You just need `moment-with-locales.js`, since it's the same moment library but including the locales files. Try removing `moment.min.js` from your project and tell me what happens. It's possible that you are loading the wrong moment library, since `moment-with-locale.js` is a dependency of `angular-moment-datepicker`, while `moment.min.js` isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173857/discussion-between-pouncingpoodle-and-bastian-diaz-olave).